# How can I get new sections of fencing to match the existing fencing?

Tags: cleaning, fence, rust-proofing

I have a lot of Fencing. half of the fence has previously been Galvanized, I have also created a few new fence sections.

My problem is that when the new fence gets galvanized, it will look too clean and polished and will stick out. I know that the oxidation that happens on the fence is the protective layer that you actually dont want to clean, however in my case, I would like to make the entire fence look the same.
so the choices are to either clean the old fence in some solution (which is cheap and readily available)  or to make the new fence oxidise quicker. 
From experience, I know that the new fence will take a few months to start looking like the existing fence.

Any Ideas here?

Comment: This seems like a lot of work for a very short-term problem. Can you really not live with slightly different shades of galvanization for a few months?

Comment: Well, i don't mind. its just that in my business I find this problem often (its more of a personal interest question)..

Answer (score 1):

The original galvanizing of the fence was in a bath of molten tin ([hot dip galvanizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-dip_galvanization)).

Since this is not practical for the old fence, there are cold galvanizing compounds.  They are zinc rich paints.

They will not stop rust that has broken through the original coating.  Rust must be removed, then coat the bare steel.

The aerosol versions would be very expensive for painting fence, but the compound is available in a brush on version.  Search "Cold Galvanizing Compound for Corrosion Control" and look for liquid brush on versions.

Answer (score 0):

When I have used muratic acid (SureKleen) while cleaning brick, I have dulled the finish of galvanized products. It needs to be a pretty strong mix, 1-2 cups per gallon of water. Of course safety precautions will need to be taken when applying. Use a plastic garden sprayer to apply, it may only last for the one application for any metal parts in the spray head (springs etc) will be damaged over time.

Answer (score -3):

Use oil base primer for the coating of galvanished metal.You may also use vinegar.

Comment: I'm guessing (though I didn't) you were marked down for not answering the question.  Down votes should be accompanied with explanations.